# Orange3 : String Variable

Tags: orange

I do not manage to create an Orange table with StringVariables. 
The following code:

> d = Orange.data.Domain([Orange.data.StringVariable("s")])

makes this error:

> TypeError: variables must be primitive

It seems that StringVariable is for metadata only. So I'm worried about this because my data has a lot of strings that it would be crazy to put in a discrete structure (each string value is different).
Is there a solution for putting strings in a table ?

Thanks in advance for the answers,
Best,
mike

Comment: What's wrong with string variables being stored as meta data? I suppose your strings are some kind of labels? You won't be able to learn from them (say by SVM), so they belong to meta data. Does this prevent you from doing something that you could if they were among the "normal" attributes?

Comment: Ok, it seems I misunderstood the "meta data" signification :(. But, as my code line (the first in my message) doesn't work, how should I declare the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old but I found it via Google and wanted to provide a simple example of how to use meta "columns".

You need to specify the meta variables the same way you specify the "normal" variables just do it inside the `metas` parameter inside the `Domain` constructor.

```
from Orange.data import *

taskid = StringVariable(name="taskid")
logdata = StringVariable(name="logdata")

domain = Domain([] , metas=[taskid, logdata])

data = Table(domain, [
["uuid1","some more stuff"],
["uuid2","some more stuff"]
]);

out_data = data;
```